# linear algebra find max and symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working through the following problems and have gotten stuck. I can do (1) and (2) for both groups but am not sure how to go about doing the other questions(find max, and the two questions for symmetric matrix).

[image]

For Find max my attempts look like this:

[image]

I can then simplify it down to get a strange answer but I don't think it is right.

As for (3) and (4) of the second part i'm not sure at all.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the eigenvalues that you got?

Comment: Hint: In the expression you want to maximize, rewrite $A$ (How can $\phi$ help?). Note that it is sufficient to only consider $v$ that suffice $||v||=1$ when finding the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum, you can use the fact that any vector $v$ can be written as $v=a_1\phi_1+a_2\phi_2+a_3\phi_3$ for some $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \mathbb{R}$, which can be rewritten as $$v=\Phi.\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\ a_2 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix}.$$
According to question $(2)$, you then have $\|v\|^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2$. On the other hand, since the $\phi_i$ are eigenvectors of $A$ (which is symmetric), you get $$v^TAv= (a_1\phi_1+a_2\phi_2+a_3\phi_3)^T(a_1\lambda_1\phi_1+a_2\lambda_2\phi_2+a_3\lambda_3\phi_3)=\lambda_1a_1^2+\lambda_2a_2^2+\lambda_3a_3^2$$(where the $\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$ corresponding to the $\phi_i$'s).

So you are left with trying to find the maximum of $$\frac{\lambda_1a_1^2+\lambda_2a_2^2+\lambda_3a_3^2}{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2},$$which is simply the biggest $\lambda_i$.

For the other question, you can deduce from point $(2)$ that for a diagonalizable matrix $A$ (and in particular a symmetric one), $Tr(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$. Since the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of those of $A$, you are left with proving that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\right)^2.$$You can do this by simply expanding the square in the right-hand term : you get all the squares of the left-hand term, plus twice the sum of all terms of the form $\lambda_i\lambda_j$ with $i\neq j$, which is non-negative since all $\lambda_i$'s are.

For the last one, I think you can show that $Tr(AB)$ defines an inner product on the vector space of symmetric matrices:

- symmetry is simply the first point;
- bilinearity comes from bilinearity of bilinear product and linearity of the trace;
- positive-definiteness follows from my answer to point $(3)$.

With that in mind, the inequality is simply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. (This is a particular case of what is called the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product).)